# For Loop in jade template engine

Tags: node.js, pug

I use a simple loop in jade template engine to list my all employees. 
Here is my code.

```
extends ../layout/main

block content
  style(type='text/css').
    .container.createEmployee {
    float: left;
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 40px;
  body
    .container.createEmployee
      h3
        a(href='/employees/create') Create Employee
      h1 Employee List
            if employee.length > 0
                for(var i=0 i<employee.length i++)
      table.table.table-striped
        thead
          tr
            th No#
            th Employee Name
            th Position
        tbody
          tr
            td
              a(href='/employees/show/ #{employee[i]._id}') #{employee[i].name}
            //- td   1
            //- td   Moaiz pervaiz
            td #{employee[i].position}
            //- td Software Developer
      div No employees found.
```

But it show me the error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I cannot get why this error come and please check my `if` condition and `for` loop. I use it correct or not. Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Here is my controller code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Employee = require("../models/employee");

var employeeController = {};

employeeController.list = function(req, res) {
Employee.find({}).exec(function (err, employees) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err);
  }
  else {
    res.render("../views/employees/index", {employees: employees});
  }
});
};

employeeController.show = function(req, res) {
Employee.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).exec(function (err, employee) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err);
  }
  else {
    res.render("../views/employees/show", {employee: employee});
  }
});
};


employeeController.create = function(req, res) {
  res.render("../views/employees/create");
};

employeeController.save = function(req, res) {
  var employee = new Employee(req.body);

employee.save(function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.render("../views/employees/create");
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully created an employee.");
    res.redirect("/employees/show/"+employee._id);
  }
 });
 };


employeeController.edit = function(req, res) {
 Employee.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).exec(function (err, employee) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err);
  }
  else {
    res.render("../views/employees/edit", {employee: employee});
  }
});
};


employeeController.update = function(req, res) {
  Employee.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: { name: req.body.name, address: req.body.address, position: req.body.position, salary: req.body.salary }}, { new: true }, function (err, employee) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.render("../views/employees/edit", {employee: req.body});
  }
  res.redirect("/employees/show/"+employee._id);
});
};


employeeController.delete = function(req, res) {
 Employee.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Employee deleted!");
    res.redirect("/employees");
  }
});
};


module.exports = employeeController;
```

Comment: You should read the [pug guide to iteration](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html).

Comment: i read it but i am doubtful for this i implement and why give the error cannot undefined@Graham

Comment: Where is your `each` statement?  Please read the docs again carefully.

Comment: i use for loop there not foreach @Graham

Comment: Please read the docs, the answer to your question is in the very first section in the link above.  Pug doesn't use for loops.  I've voted to close this question as your issue is caused by a typographical error.